# How do I add a dropout layer before a hidden layer in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am little bit confused on adding a dropout layer before my second hidden layer in tensorflow?

```
w_int = tf.initializers.glorot_normal()
w = tf.Variable(w_init(shape=[512, 256]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(256))

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
layer2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w), b))

layer2_drop = tf.nn.dropout(layer2, keep_prob=keep_prob)
```

and during training I can pass:

```
sess.run([adam, w], feed_dict={x: train_x, y_: train_y, keep_prob: 0.5})
```

and during testing I can set keep_prob to 1:

```
sess.run(cost_drop, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels,  keep_prob: 1.0})
```

If you check tensorflow page for [`tf.nn.dropout`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout) you can see `keep_prob` is deprecated and we should use `rate` parameter instead. 
So instead of passing `keep_prob = keep_prob` like above do i need to pass `rate = 1 - keep_prob` in `layer2_drop`?

If not how should I use `rate` instead of `keep_prob` on `layer2_drop` And If I use rate do I need to pass `keep_prob` at training and testing respectively?

> Warning: SOME ARGUMENTS ARE DEPRECATED: (keep_prob). They will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Please use rate instead of keep_prob. Rate should be set to rate = 1 - keep_prob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are perfectly fine using `keep_prob` for now if you can tolerate the warning message.

In the future, only `rate` will be available and to update you should use suggested formula `rate=1.-keep_prob`.

While it might be possible to use both keep_prob and rate at the same time, please don't. Just stick to the latest attribute `rate`. You don't have to set up them both since they are describing the same thing and only one will actually be used.